# How can I detect a connection failure in gorm?

Tags: error-handling, go, go-gorm

I'm writing a small, simple web app in go using the [gorm ORM](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm).

Since the database can fail independently of the web application, I'd like to be able to identify errors that correspond to this case so that I can reconnect to my database without restarting the web application.

**Motivating example:**

Consider the following code:

```
var mrs MyRowStruct
db := myDB.Model(MyRowStruct{}).Where("column_name = ?", value).First(&mrs)
return &mrs, db.Error
```

1. In the event that `db.Error != nil`, how can I programmatically determine if the error stems from a database connection problem?
2. From my reading, I understand that `gorm.DB` **does not** represent a connection, so do I even have to worry about reconnecting or re-issuing a call to `gorm.Open` if a database connection fails?
3. Are there any common patterns for handling database failures in Go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gorm appears to swallow database driver errors and emit only it's own classification of error types (see [`gorm/errors.go`](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/errors.go)).  Connection errors do not currently appear to be reported.

Consider submitting an issue or pull request to expose the database driver error directly.

**[Original]**

Try inspecting the runtime type of `db.Error` per the advice in the [gorm readme "Error Handling" section](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm#error-handling).

Assuming it's an error type returned by your database driver you can likely get a specific code that indicates connection errors.  For example, if you're using PostgreSQL via the pq library then you might try something like this:

```
import "github.com/lib/pq"

// ...

if db.Error != nil {
  pqerr, ok := err.(*pq.Error)
  if ok && pqerr.Code[0:2] == "08" {
    // PostgreSQL "Connection Exceptions" are class "08"
    // http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/errcodes-appendix.html#ERRCODES-TABLE
    // Do something for connection errors...
  } else {
    // Do something else with non-pg error or non-connection error...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  Your snippet answers my question perfectly.